# Angular moving scope variable from controller to directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have created a directive like this

```
  .directive('optionLabel', function() {
    'use strict';
    return {
      replace: true,
      restrict: 'AE',
      template: '<div class="error-msg col-xs-12 intelligent-group col-centered"><h1 translate>{{ optionLabel }}</h1></div>'
    };
  })
```

Right now the Scope optionLabel is set in each of the controllers that uses this directive as such.

```
$scope.optionLabel = labelService.getOptionLabel(search.searchType);
```

How could I set this in the directive directly, rather than doing this code repeated in like 5 controllers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use link in which you have access to your scope :

```
.directive('optionLabel', function() {
'use strict';
return {
  replace: true,
  restrict: 'AE',
  template: '<div class="error-msg col-xs-12 intelligent-group col-centered"><h1 translate>{{ optionLabel }}</h1></div>',
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
scope.optionLabel = labelService.getOptionLabel(search.searchType);
};
})
```

Don't forget to inject labelService in your directive.